# How to make jQuery Validate() rule to be onkeyup false?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have written seprate rule for **jQuery `validate()`** named as `login_auth` and I want that rule to be **not called on every key press** but I want **all other rule to be called `onkeyup`**.  It means all other inbuilt **rules** like `email` and `password` should be called on every key up but only `login_auth` should be called only on `onfocusout` or `blur`.

Comment: If you want help, please show your form code... both HTML and jQuery.

Comment: answer to a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17096209/678338

Answer (score 4):

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ 
  onkeyup: function(element) { 
      if (element.name == '#emailid') { 
          return false; 
      }
  }
});
```

In a form, if you want to stop keyup event for a particular id, try this.

Answer (score 3):

This is my best answer until you post your actual HTML and jQuery.

I know of no way to apply any plugin options selectively.... rather they get applied to each instance of the plugin.

Therefore, I propose two forms so that you can have two unique instances of `.validate()`, and apply the `onkeyup: false` option on one form, while allowing `onkeyup` to function normally on the other form.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="authForm" action="#">
    login: <input type="text" name="login" /><br />
</form>

<form id="Form" action="yourAction" method="yourMethod">
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#authForm').validate({
        onkeyup: false,
        rules: {
            login: {
                login_auth: true,  // your custom rule
                required: true
            }
        }
    });

    $('#Form').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            if ($('#authForm').valid()) {
                form.submit();
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            $('#authForm').valid(); // force validation on first form when this form has error
            error.insertAfter(element); // default error placement
        }
    });

});​
```

[**Working Demo:**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkjk/5/)

http://jsfiddle.net/4Hkjk/5/